# Procedurally set ImageVIew of GridView based on number

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-fragments

I'm attempting to create a Gridview of icons with the Imageview set to one of two images like in my example below:

[image]

I'm retrieving two values from the sqlite content provider, one for the number of stamps and the other for the max number of stamps.

I use a custom adapter with a view holder pattern so I attempt to set the model onLoadFinished() in the Fragment.  The model I've currently tried is an int[] with either value of 0 or 1 in the values to determine if green stamp is used or gray.  This isn't working however as nothing is being displayed in the GridView.

Here's the code snippet from onLoadFinished() from the Fragment:

```
imageSourceModel = new int[data.getInt(data.getColumnIndex(RewardsEntry.COLUMN_REW_MAX_POINTS))];
        int i = data.getInt(data.getColumnIndex(RewardsEntry.COLUMN_REW_POINTS));
        for (int j = 0; j < imageSourceModel.length; j++, i--)   {
            if (i > 0)  {
                imageSourceModel[j] = 1;
            } else  {
                imageSourceModel[j] = 0;
            }
        }
        stampGridAdapter.setModel(imageSourceModel);
```

and the code from the custom Adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_discover, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    if (model[i] > 0)   {
        viewHolder.stampView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_approved_stamp);
    } else  {
        viewHolder.stampView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_approved_stamp_disabled);
    }
    return view;
}
```

And simple ViewHolder:

```
private class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView stampView;

    public ViewHolder(View view)    {
        stampView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_stamp_image);
    }
}
```

If I had to guess, I would say that it fails because of the creation order such that getView() is completed before onLoadFinished() can pass the model in.  I'm just not sure how to work around this or what other methods I could use.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think I can guess what you want to achieve, a user has a certain amount of reward points of a maximum number ? In your picture that would be 4/9 ?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Its easy to show the numerical value but in an effort to be user friendly, I'm wanting a graphical representation of the number of 'stamps' a user has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you want to achieve, this seems unnecessary complicated to me, especially the double variable loop. To cut it simple I'd just do this:

in onLoadFinished()

```
int maxPoints = data.getInt(data.getColumnIndex(RewardsEntry.COLUMN_REW_MAX_POINTS));
int currentPoints = data.getInt(data.getColumnIndex(RewardsEntry.COLUMN_REW_POINTS));
mGridView.setAdapter(new RewardPointAdapter(getActivity(), currentPoints, maxPoints);
```

your adapter could look like this:

```
public class RewardPointAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private int mMaxRewardPoints;
    private int mCurrentRewardPoints;

    public RewardPointAdapter(Context context, int currentRewardPoints, int maxRewardPoints) {
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mMaxRewardPoints = maxRewardPoints;
        mCurrentRewardPoints = currentRewardPoints;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mMaxRewardPoints;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_discover, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if (position < mCurrentRewardPoints)   {
            viewHolder.stampView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_approved_stamp);
        } else  {
            viewHolder.stampView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_approved_stamp_disabled);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView stampView;

        public ViewHolder(View view)    {
            stampView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_stamp_image);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you are absolutely correct!  works like a charm now.  I think I was dubious on setting the adapter in onLoadFinished() as I wasn't sure what atrocities that could cause during run.  Thanks for the help, Su-Au.